# Undefined objects from json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-places-api, sidebar

Here I have a code for creating map and sibar with links, but in infowindow all is ok, and in sidebar I only get undefined text:

http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/23 (just click submit)

So what is exactly the problem?

CODE:

```
 var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers["+parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)+"],\"mouseover\");'>"+place.name+"</a><br>";
    document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [RadarSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests).

From the documentation:

> PlaceResult objects returned by radarSearch() will only include the geometry.location and reference properties.

There is no .name property

Comment: You need to use the [NearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) which is limited to 60 results in three separate groups of 20.

Comment: yes but please show me in example in my code, can you fix sidebar to use nearbySearch ?

Comment: That is what I said in my comment... 60 results in three separate groups of 20.