# Google Maps API - return more than 60 place names for radar search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing a radar search for places by keyword and trying to populate a sidebar with the names of places returned. A radar search request returns up to 200 results but (to my understanding) a place details request returns up to 60 results.

How can I return all results from the place details requests? My idea is to pause for a few seconds between requests but want to see if anyone has a better solution.

Part of code that performs the search and sidebar populating:

```
function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    location: map.center,
    radius: '500',
    keyword: 'pandas',
    rankBy: 'distance'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
     for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
         service.getDetails(result, function(place, status) {
             placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '</li>';      
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined objects from json with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499291/undefined-objects-from-json-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A radar search doesn't return the place.name, just the location and a reference to get more information.  It should return up to 200 results.

Comment: Yes it returns 200 results but you can get the place name for only 60 results. My question is how to get place names for all 200 results.

Comment: note: in my code I'm using the place details request on the results returned from radar search.

Comment: The fact that 60 results contain the place name is not documented and may stop working at any time.

Comment: And it occurs to me that this is just an attempt to get around the query limit on normal Places (non-radar) queries.  The same restriction should exist (only 60 results in groups of 20).